# How to "Global Ignore" / "Hell Ban" someone, restrict post visibility to the author only?

Tags: user-access, moderation

I'm looking for a way to deal with trolls by making any post they make invisible to everyone except them. This is known as a number of names "Global Ignore", "Hell Ban", "Troll Hack", "Tachy Goes to Coventry".

How can I do that?

Comment: As much as I'd love if something like this existed, technically plugin recommendations are off-topic per the [FAQ]

Comment: Oh sorry, familiar with the other StackExchange sites, new to this one. Odd rule though as it isn't a rule on the Drupal StackExchange site but I guess that's an example of the Drupal community being less "competitive" around modules.

Comment: It's not about competition, it's due to the sheer amount of plugins WordPress has, which inundates the site with questions that no one can answer or are just opinion based.

Comment: I have edited the question to bring it on topic. Hope you don’t mind. :) Oh, and look at [Drupal’s answer rate](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered): even worse than ours. This is why a clear focus is so important.

Comment: Agree to disagree :)